# Cannot retrieve env variable set in parent folder's htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, environment-variables

Suppose that I have the following file/directory structure:

```
/.htaccess
/index.php
/module/.htaccess
/module/module.php
```

In `/.htaccess` I have:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^.*" HTTP_WTLIB_VERSION=5.2 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/REST/(.*)
RewriteRule ^REST/(.*)/(.*) /wtlib_%{ENV:HTTP_WTLIB_VERSION}/REST/$1/$2 [L,QSA]
```

In `/module/.htaccess` I have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule .* /wtlib_%{ENV:HTTP_WTLIB_VERSION}/modules/post/admin/ [L,NC,QSA]
```

But it did not work. Is this actually possible?

---

Update:
It was asked in the comments that I should provide full details.
The actual `/.htaccess` file content is:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +Indexes +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteBase /

SetEnvIf Request_URI "^.*" HTTP_WTLIB_VERSION=5.2

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/REST/(.*)
RewriteRule ^REST/(.*)/(.*) /wtlib_%{ENV:HTTP_WTLIB_VERSION}/REST/$1/$2 [L,QSA]

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddType text/x-component .htc


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin$ /admin/ [L]


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/modules/(.*)/(.*)
RewriteRule ^ - [env=ActiveModuleName:%1]

RewriteRule ^admin/modules/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /wtlib_%{ENV:HTTP_WTLIB_VERSION}/modules/$1/admin/$2/$3/$4/$5 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/modules/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /wtlib_%{ENV:HTTP_WTLIB_VERSION}/modules/$1/admin/$2/$3/$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/modules/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /wtlib_%{ENV:HTTP_WTLIB_VERSION}/modules/$1/admin/$2/$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/modules/(.*)/(.*) /wtlib_%{ENV:HTTP_WTLIB_VERSION}/modules/$1/admin/$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/search /wtlib_%{ENV:HTTP_WTLIB_VERSION}/apps/admin/search.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /wtlib_%{ENV:HTTP_WTLIB_VERSION}/apps/admin/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /wtlib_%{ENV:HTTP_WTLIB_VERSION}/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^wtlib/(.*)$ /wtlib_%{ENV:HTTP_WTLIB_VERSION}/$1 [L,QSA]

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RewriteRule ^ - [env=dd:%{REQUEST_URI}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.PNG|\.jpg|\.JPG|\.gif|\.GIF|\.jpeg|\.JPEG|\.bmp|\.js|\.css|\.htm|\.html|\.htc|\.ico)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]
```

And the /module/.htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule .* /wtlib_%{ENV:HTTP_WTLIB_VERSION}/modules/post/admin/ [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: It just doesnt redirect to where it suppose to. Displays the folder list on the browser. If type the version number manually, it works.

Comment: I just updated the question. It could be a little challenging to figure out the entire structure by looking at these, if needed I can provide a better folder structure too.

Comment: I have been trying to setup a URL for you to access, but the project's  DNS settings are not properly setup yet, and I could not setup a fake link. I was working on local server. I guess, it is not quite possible to figure something without an actual working url?

Comment: Oh, sorry my bad :( it is: http://domain.com/admin/modules/hotel/?a=list

Comment: It was to simplify my question. the real path is: /wtlib_5.2/modules/hotel/.htaccess

Comment: I understand but `domain.com/admin/module/` will not use `/module/.htaccess`

Comment: RewriteRule ^admin/modules/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /wtlib_%{ENV:HTTP_WTLIB_VERSION}/modules/$1/admin/$2/$3 [L,QSA]   this will redirect to /wtlib_5.2/modules/hotel/